# "Data is not ready error" , error code 22, Autodesk Reality Capture API

Tags: autodesk-realitycapture

I'm trying to create a 3D rendering of an environment whose pictures I have uploaded. According to the API step-by-step tutorial, I got until the very last part where I download the processed data. Unfortunately I get this following message no matter what set of pictures I use. "Error":{"code":"22","msg":"Data is not ready"}}'

Any idea on how to fix?

`https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/tutorials/create-3d-mesh-from-photos/`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a look at the following blog post on Reality Capture API https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hitchhikers-guide-reality-capture-api that might help you to debug and identify the source of the problems.

The source of the problem could vary, but usually it is related to either **you haven't uploaded enough images** or images (or some of them) were not being properly uploaded.

Since you are using the sample, most probably you tried to generate an object using too few photos.